# A general Turan-like question

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Thinking of an edge as of a $2$-clique, it's natural to consider a slightly more general question than Turan considered in his celebrated theorem: **given $r \le k \le n$, what is the maximal possible number of $r$-cliques in a graph $X$ on $n$ vertices without $k$-cliques?** Has this question been considered in the literature?

Yet more generally, given two graphs $G$ and $H$ and a number $n$, one could ask for the **maximum of the homomorphism number $hom(G,X)$ over all graphs $X$ on $n$ vertices satisfying $hom(H,X)=0$.** Any references for this one maybe?

Comment: The opposite question, about the minimum number of $r$-cliques in a graph without $k$-independent sets (which is basically equivalent for $r=2$) was asked by Erdős in 1962. A reference to some results as well as discussion of prior work is contained in Minimum Number of k-Cliques in Graphs with Bounded Independence Number by Oleg Pikhurko and Emil R. Vaughan in Combinatorics, Probability, and Computing https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00279952

Comment: The first question was answered by Zykov; see https://users.monash.edu.au/~davidwo/papers/Wood-GC07.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The first question was studied by Moon and Moser. You could read a proof of Turán's theorem using this idea in the [article by Aigner](http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2014-15/1term/ma121a/Aigner%20-%20Turans%20Graph%20Theorem.pdf) (it is the third proof).

Even more general questions have been studied: what are the inequalities that are satisfied by the number of homomorphisms from a collection $H_1,\dotsc,H_k$ of graphs. The general problem is known to be undecidable, thanks to [Hatami and Norine](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2382), but it has not stopped people from proving many results of this kind.